# rbind in loop only binds numbers not characters

Tags: r, loops, rbind

I am having some problems with the rbind in my loop.

It doesnt seem to work for some reason, I run the script to print out a list of characters in the dataframe with "ak","aj","ar","tr" in my rows which I need.

It works with numbers. ie - super <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4)) but it just doesn't seem to characters.

Anyone know why and how to get it to work with characters as well?

Thank you

```
super <- data.frame(c("ak","aj","ar","tr"))
test1 <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:4)
{
  test1 <- rbind(test1,super[i,1])
}
print(test1)
```

Comment: @Solvi 's answer is great. Your problem in your method is that the dataframe you create has a factor column and not a character one. So, it uses numbers that represent the factor's classes.

Comment: Google search 'growing objects in r' to see why this method is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Now I don't know in what context you are using this but this can be achieved without a for loop:

```
super <- as.matrix(c("ak","aj","ar","tr"))
test1 <- data.frame()
test1 <- rbind(test1,super)
print(test1)
```

as.matrix() is used to make super a column vector.

Or simpler:

```
test1 <- data.frame(super=c("ak","aj","ar","tr"))
```

If you prefer the for loop this works as well:

```
super <- c("ak","aj","ar","tr")
test1 <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:4){
    test1[i,1] <- super[i]
}
print(test1)
```

About why the numbers displays in your example, it looks like the numbers represent alphabetical ordering of the characters, I'm not sure why though.